# Jacoco executable generated via an agent attached to tomcat is not generating the proper code coverage data

Tags: java, automated-tests, integration-testing, tomcat8, jacoco

I am using the following JAVA_OPTS to attach the jacoco agent to the tomcat JVM

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/etc/init.d/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/**/logs/jacoco.exec,includes=*"
```

I ran my automation against the service and the exec was generated, however, the exec file is only about 2k bytes once I shutdown the tomcat instance. Moreover I can only find coverage data about some tomcat packages.

How can I find my codes coverage data?